# IOCTL Code for Windows driver

Tags: ida, windows, kernel-mode, driver

Recently I tried to obtain OICTL Codes from the iscflashx64.sys driver and I have found it in DispatchDeviceControl function. After driver being installed and have started with SCM it displayed in WinObj. when I invoke DeviceIOControl  function with this codes in my user-land app it returns "1" error code. that means my codes is invalid.

Here is IDA view capture and userapp code[image]

Next:

```
lea     rdx, cs:10000h
movzx   eax, ds:(byte_1C9C8 - 10000h)[rdx+rsi]
mov     ecx, ds:(off_1C988 - 10000h)[rdx+rax*4]
add     rcx, rdx
jmp     rcx             ; switch jump
```

And function call:

```
lea     rcx, [rsp+188h+PhysicalAddress]
call    MSR_read1
jmp     short loc_1C2BC
```

in userapp:

```
#define IOCTL_READ_MSR\
 CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x2237134, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
...

    bool msr_get(unsigned int reg, unsigned long long *val)
  {
    if (hHandle == NULL)
    {
        printf("## ERROR: Not initialized\n");
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwBytes = 0;
    UCHAR Request[0x100];
    ZeroMemory(&Request, sizeof(Request));

    *(PDWORD)(Request + 0x08) = reg;

    // send request to the driver
    if (DeviceIoControl(
        hHandle, IOCTL_READ_MSR,
        &Request, sizeof(Request), &Request, sizeof(Request),
        &dwBytes, NULL))
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER Val;

        Val.HighPart = *(PDWORD)(Request + 0x0c);
        Val.LowPart = *(PDWORD)(Request + 0x00);

        *val = Val.QuadPart;

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("## ERROR DeviceIoControl() %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    return false;
 }
```

After googling I found [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering/comments/1sk43l/question_retrieving_ioctl_codes_from_a_driver/). So this step by step solution does`t work for me. May be problem in switch case tables, but IDA get comments that seems like a codes like that:

```
loc_1C55A:
sub     esi, 222406h
jz      loc_1C6E7
```

What is going wrong? Will be very grateful for any suggestions or just a common techniques in using IOCTL.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA comments list case values in decimal, so you need to either use `2237134` as decimal in your code, or convert it to hex (i.e. `0x2222CE`) first.

Additional issue is that the value 0x2222CE is the *full* IOCTL code while the [`CTL_CODE` macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543023(v=vs.85).aspx) accepts a function value (bits 2:12 of the code).
Using [Online IOCTL decoder](https://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=229), we can see that the function is 0x8b3.

So you can use either

```
#define IOCTL_READ_MSR\
 CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x8b3, METHOD_OUT_DIRECT, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
```

or

```
#define IOCTL_READ_MSR 0x2222CE
```

(both should result in the same value).

Comment: That works for msr reading ! 
Now I have BSOD with 3b code(exception while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code) after invoking DeviceIOControl with my MSR_WRITE code.
Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, we're not a debugging site; please try to figure it out yourself or ask for help on SO

Answer (score 2):

you can use a python script to find all the IOCTL codes in your binary, here is a script created for the very same purpose :
    # Find the IoControlCodes corresponding to
    # calls to DeviceIOControl within a binary

```
from idaapi import *
from idautils import *
from idc import *

##########################################################
# This class implements a fifo queue
class fqueue(list):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def push(self, a):
        self.append(a)
        if len(self) > self.n:
            self.pop(0)

##########################################################

gpRegList = ['eax', 'ebx', 'ecx', 'edx']
ioccList = []
callerList = []
pushQueue = fqueue(2)

dioc_ea = LocByName("DeviceIoControl") # EA

print "DeviceIoControl found at 0x%08x" % dioc_ea

for caller in XrefsTo(dioc_ea, True):
    # This is the address (within a function)
    # where the reference was made
    caller_ea = caller.frm

    if caller_ea not in callerList:
        # IDA Pro shifts duplicates, get rid of them
        callerList.append(caller_ea)
        print "xref @ 0x%08x (%s)" % (caller_ea, GetFunctionName(caller_ea))
    else:
        continue

    # The dwIoControlCode must be the second 
    # PUSH xxx before the CALL instruction
    # So we need to keep track of the PUSH instructions
    for ins in FuncItems(caller_ea):
        disasm = GetDisasm(ins)
        if "push" in disasm:
            # Save the PUSH instruction's operand
            pushQueue.push(GetOpnd(ins, 0))
        elif ins == caller_ea:
            # At this moment we hit the corresponding CALL instruction
            # First item in Queue is second "oldest" push
            iocc = pushQueue[0]

            if iocc in gpRegList:
                print "NOTE: IoControlCode was %s at 0x%08x. Check manually" % (iocc, caller_ea)
            else:
                if pushQueue[0] not in ioccList:
                    ioccList.append(pushQueue[0])
        else:
            pass

# Print all the gathered IoControlCodes

print "%d IoControlCodes found!" % len(ioccList)

for io in ioccList:
    print "[*]", io
```

run the script using IDA when disassembling the binary and it will do the magic for you, 
hope this helps!

Comment: Does not work in IDA 7.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Just tested the script on IDA 7 and it works fine, make sure your python version is 2.7. 
a stack trace of the given error would be more helpfull

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I've py 2.7. Other py scripts work fine (e.g. diaphora). Though I'm not deeply familiar with python I shall find why it doesn't work.

Comment: good luck with that, I'm here to help if you need any :D

Comment: I'm on IDA 7.4 and the script doesn't work for me either. It doesn't throw any errors either....