# How to get IOCTLs from all NtDeviceIoControlFile function call?

Tags: ida, windows, idapython

Inspired by [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18399/23069) about RE-ing IOCTLs, I tried to get the IOCTLs from
[`NtDeviceIoControlFile()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntdeviceiocontrolfile) syscall. Here is an example of that syscall
in `Beep()` function in `KernelBase.dll` file:

- In x86_64 (__fastcall) Assembly language:

```
and     [rsp+72], ebx                   ; OutputBufferLength
and     [rsp+64], rbx                   ; OutputBuffer
mov     dword ptr [rsp+56], 8           ; InputBufferLength
lea     rax, [rsp+152]
mov     [rsp+48], rax                   ; InputBuffer
mov     dword ptr [rsp+40], 10000h      ; IoControlCode
lea     rax, [rsp+78h+var_18]
mov     [rsp+32], rax                   ; IoStatusBlock
xor     r9d, r9d                        ; ApcContext
xor     r8d, r8d                        ; ApcRoutine
xor     edx, edx                        ; Event
mov     rcx, [rsp+144]                  ; FileHandle
call    cs:__imp_NtDeviceIoControlFile
test    eax, eax
```

- In C language:

```
NTSTATUS Status;
Status = NtDeviceIoControlFile(FileHandle,
                               NULL,
                               NULL,
                               NULL,
                               &IoStatusBlock,
                               0x10000u,
                               &InputBuffer,
                               InputBufferLength,
                               OutputBuffer,
                               OutputBufferLength);
```

I tried this code in IDA Python to list all the cross references of that syscall:

```
# Global arrays
XrefList = []

# Get imported function address
FuncAddr = LocByName("__imp_NtDeviceIoControlFile")
print "NtDeviceIoControlFile found at 0x%08x" % FuncAddr

# Iterate over all call references
for xref in XrefsTo(FuncAddr, True):
    if xref.frm not in XrefList:
        XrefList.append(xref.frm)
        print "xref @ 0x%08x (%s)" % (xref.frm, GetFunctionName(xref.frm))
    else:
        continue
```

This code can successfully list all the syscall in a list. But I want to list
all the IOCTLs values at `RSP+40` offset i.e. 6th parameter. What code should I add?
If you have any suggestion with IDC code I shall appreciate it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After iterating some arbitrary functions in [IDA Python docs](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/), I found a function
[get_arg_addrs()](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_typeinf-module.html#get_arg_addrs) which shows the argument I need. Here is the Python code
that I have appended with my question's code.

```
# Get IOCTLs
for i in XrefList:
    fifth_arg = idaapi.get_arg_addrs(i)[5]
    ioctl = GetOpnd(fifth_arg, 1)
    print "IOCTL: %s" % ioctl
```

This a for loop iterates over the `XrefList` array that had been created from previous operations.
Then find the 5th argument and the 1st operand which is the IOCTL value.
This method also works with `DeviceIoControl()`. But The code has one caveat.
If `NtDeviceIoControlFile()` is used in some wrapper subroutine
then the output of above code will be the CPU register name.